# Utilizando ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como criar um progressBar onde, ao clicar em um botão para abrir outra tela, o progressBar fosse mostrando, e ao abrir a outra tela, o progressBar saia da tela. Como faço isso? Já tenho as duas telas, quero apenas inserir o progressBar.

Comment: http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2015/03/android-example-progress-bar-tutorial.html

Comment: Reinaldo, o nosso fórum é pra tirar dúvidas técnicas, e não pra que façam o trabalho por vc, o ideal é que vc pesquise sobre o que vc quer, tente fazer, e caso tenha alguma dificuldade durante a sua programação, vc venha tirar as dúvidas aqui juntamente com o seu código

Comment: @Reinaldo, poste o seu código que tentamos auxiliar, ninguem vai postar uma solução de uma pergunta sem ter o minimo de tentativa, pra isso existe a documentação oficial.

Answer (score -1):

Reinaldo você tem que fazer o seguinte, depois de inserir o progress bar dentro do seu layout, você vai ter que declarar ele na sua activity, declarando ele você coloca dentro da sua função para chamar a segunda tela o seguinte "progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);", depois disso vá na sua segunda activity e dentro do oncreate escreva "progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);". Vai funcionar.
Lembrando que o "progressbar" é o nome que declarou para o progress bar, não o id.

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.